# On Apple developer portal recently generated provisioning profiles marked "invalid"

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

for an enterprise developer account, I have several provisioning profiles generated recently which are now marked as invalid, but there have been no changes to the bundle ID or anything else. Has anyone else has a similar experience?

As far as I'm aware, the fact that they are marked invalid doesn't pose a problem to deployed apps that use that use those provisioning profiles, nor even prevents signing with those provisioning profiles, it just prevents download of the profiles if they weren't already downloaded

Comment: Has the certificate expired?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that information - the enterprise distribution certificate is good for 2 more years